# Small p with dot below

Tags: luatex, unicode

Is it at all possible to place a dot below p? I am referring to the dots as the one in ḥ.
For what I am aware, this character is not in unicode (should be in Latin Extended Additional, by having a look at the table), and thus my question comes:

is it possible to produce a symbol that is not in unicode?

Btw, I am using LuaLaTeX to compile and the EBGaramond font with fontspec

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\d{p}
\d{o}
\d{g}
\d{n}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Combining characters sometimes need some help if the font designer didn't set up anchors for them.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\pdb}{%
  p\llap{^^^^0323\kern0.4\fontcharwd\font`p}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\gdb}{%
  g\llap{\lower0.9\fontchardp\font`g\hbox{^^^^0323\kern0.5\fontcharwd\font`g}}%
}

\begin{document}

\pdb\d{o}\gdb\d{n}

\end{document}
```

Here the combining character U+0323 COMBINING DOT BELOW is placed in a zero width box by itself, so it doesn't combine. A suitable kern is added at the end, which moves left the character.

The amount of adjustment has to be computed on a font basis, I'm afraid.

If you want to move down the dot below the p, use the definition of `\gdb` as a template.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The optional argument to `\stackunder` specifies the gap.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
ha\stackunder[-1.5pt]{p}{.}\stackunder[0pt]{p}{.}y
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

There's a [COMBINING DOT BELOW (U+0323)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0323/index.htm) character, but it does not look really good with EB Garamond (it works with H, but not P). However, you can adjust kerning so it fits the P letter:

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newcommand{\mydoT}[1]{#1\kern -.2em \char"0323\relax}
\begin{document}
\Huge 
p\char"0323\relax
    
p\kern -.2em \char"0323\relax

\mydoT{p}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can put the dot below p using `\vtop` primitive. You can place the dot using `\kern` to the arbitrary place relative to the p character. My macro places the dot below the stem of p (in Computer Modern). May be a little modification shoud be done when you are using another font.

```
\def\dotp{\leavevmode\vtop{\offinterlineskip\hbox{p}\kern.07em\hbox{.}}}

Test: pa\dotp a
```